# NSUserDefaults nil after setting an object for key

Tags: ios, swift, null, nsuserdefaults

I am facing an issue that I can't find help from google or other questions solving or giving me explaination related to `NSUserDefaults`

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let s = defaults.objectForKey("troll")

if s == nil {
    defaults.setObject("This is important message", forKey: "troll")
    defaults.synchronize()
}

print(s as! String) // It returns nil
```

it turns out if I try to access the object right after setting it, it returns nil!

BUT, if run my project again on my device then:

`s as! String // returns "This is important message"`

My question is WHY it's not returning string value instead of returning nil at the first time, but second project run time returns that string value.

I need it to return string value at the first time. Is that possible? Could someone point out that what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to kick yourself...

```
if s == nil {
```

So you just said that `s` is nil, I got it...

```
print(s as! String) // It returns nil
```

Well, what do you expect it to be, you just said it was nil! :-)

I think you meant to do this:

```
let s = defaults.objectForKey("troll")
if s == nil {
    s = "This is important message"
    defaults.setObject(s, forKey: "troll")
    defaults.synchronize()
}
print(s as! String) // no longer returns nil
```

You, sir, owe me a beer.

Comment: I am indeed gonna kick myself.... the struggle was real to find that bug!!! Sometimes you just need other guy to take a look at your code, but thanks!! :)))

Comment: i still don't get it, if s == nil , he sets the value not printing it !, print function occurs after setting the value if it was nil

Comment: If the value is already in the defaults, then s != nil, you go past the block, and print gets called. If the value is not already in defaults, he creates the value, saves it out, and then exits the block and prints it out. Either way, print(s) is called. The other way to do this would be to read s again, another objectForKey after the block (or inside it).

Comment: i see, the key i got this was another objectForKey, thanks Maury :)